# Hibernate second level cache (ehcache) with inheritance strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, ehcache

I want to cache child entities which are inherited from parent configured as `strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE`. I want to apply different caching strategies on each of them and some of them I dont want to be cached at all. Is this possible? I tested it in junit test and it doesnt seem to work. I can only cache parent, which causes all childeren to be cached in the same way. When I try to cache child, no caching happens at all. I couldnt find anything in official docs, can someone help?

Comment: You need to provide some code (hibernate/cache configuration at least).

Comment: Hey Eduard, hi. Did you find a solution?